# How does Rao-Blackwellisation use only $X$ in $Y | X$ to produce the result?

Tags: monte-carlo, rao-blackwell

How does Rao-Blackwellisation use only $X$ in $Y | X$ to produce the result?

Since I read that what Rao-Blackwellisation does is find first

$$\mathbb{E}[Y | X=x] := h(x)$$

and then draws an estimate using

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n h(x_k)$$

But I'm confused about, whether this uses $Y$ or $h$ (which is $Y$) or not. Because some notes suggest that Rao-Blackwellisation "only requires the $x$s", whereas a typical Monte Carlo would calculate the $Y$s directly using their definition/distribution.

So I'm confused about, what exactly is the difference of Rao-Blackwellisation compared to Monte Carlo?

Or perhaps the difference is that rather than computing $Y$ directly from $Y$'s definition, one uses the definition for the expected value $\mathbb{E}[Y | X=x]$, which is found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

However, the nominator does contain a sum of $Y$. So one would evaluate the nominator using the p.m.f. of $Y$?

Comment: Consider a simple regression model and that you want to estimate the mean of $y$. Using the conditional mean $x_i’\beta$ rather than the full observations $y_i=x_i\beta +\epsilon$ is less variable and gives you more precision.

Answer (score 1):

A parametric Rao-Blackwellisation exploits further knowledge about the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Hence, using
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y|X=x_i]$$reduces the variance compared with using $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$$

Simulation-wise, this means that, assuming $X$ can be directly simulated, it is indeed not necessary to simulate $Y$. However in most settings, Rao-Backwellisation is associated with a joint simulation of $(X,Y)$, for instance through a Gibbs sampler.